# How to make the slide display on one another

Tags: jquery, html, css

While i hover in the Left Image it is going behind the second(right) image.

Once i hover on the first image it should slide on the top of the Right Image and Vice versa to the Left side Image.

What i have tried so far is on the the  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sulthan/T3anq/).

Here is my Screen [image]

How can i do this ?

```
.view-fifths:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -o-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-300px);
   transform: translateX(-300px);
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T3anq/2/ is this what u want?

Comment: Yes !! But the Second appears from new position. Can you make a change over it and makes it appears like the first slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Add the following css. i have remove `overflow: hidden;` in `.view` css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3anq/5)

Css Code

```
    .view:hover {
     z-index:40;
    }
   .outer {
    overflow:hidden;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, But the Second (Right) Slider appears from a New position. Can you make it appear as like of the First(Left) Slider. In Addition it works only in Chrome not in Firefox :(

Comment: It works only in Chrome, Not in Firefox (How can i update the Mozkit ?)

Comment: Which one should i use in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow ?

Answer (score 1):

Here, in this particular case, you need some tricky code:

like following :

```
.view-fifth:hover {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Remove `overflow:hidden` from view class, always add `overflow:hidden` in the parent div.

Here, add `overflow:hidden` in outer class

See Working Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/T3anq/9/)

Comment: Oh, That's Great going. Works !! I can accept only one answer. Shall upvote once i get reputation